# Upload PDF file to Gmail

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, gmail, pdf

After downloading a PDF file from Gmail with the help of [ASTRO File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.metago.astro&hl=en) in my [Samsung Galaxy S III](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S_III), I tried to find the PDF file to attach in the email (Gmail). Unfortunately, only images get attached, but none of the PDF files.

How can I do that? Where exactly am I going wrong in the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach files with the gmail app. Just click attach image, select Astro to browse and select the PDF you wish to attach

Comment: I tried the same thing... But the PDF file dint get attached at all

Comment: I just did, worked fine for me... Try using ES File Explorer